# WPF How to get TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" to show in TextBlock inside a Border

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0, textblock

I have a user control that contains a Grid and inside Border with a TextBlock inside.
All controls are bound via MVVM.

The visibility of the Border is driven by

```
IsFoundErrorsOnSave
```

and the  TextBlock Text is bound to

```
ErrorsOnSaveMessage
```

.

When error is thrown in View Model the I would like to show a trimmed message and a tooltip with a   full text. I can achieve that by a hardcoding TextBlock width.
I want my textbox to show ellipsis in XAML without hardcoding width or adding additional code in MVVM.

```html
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.BrokerAlgoDefaults.DefaultsUserCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:FlexTrade.Windows.Controls.Input.Converters;assembly=FlexTrade.Windows.Controls.Input"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.BrokerAlgoDefaults"
             xmlns:dashboard="clr-namespace:FlexTrade.Module.Dashboard;assembly=FlexTrade.Module.Dashboard"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="DefaultsUserControl"
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="400" MinWidth="300" MinHeight="100">
    <UserControl.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ThemeWindowBackgroundColor}" />
    </UserControl.Background>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FlexTrade.Windows.Visuals;component/Styles/SystemControlStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FlexTrade.Windows.VisualModels;component/Styles/Custom_Dark.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <converters:InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter" x:Shared="True"/>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <telerik:RadTabControl Grid.Row="0" TabStripPlacement="Top" TabOrientation="Horizontal" Align="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Symbol">
                <telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                    <local:SymbolUserCtrl DataContext="{Binding SymbolsViewModel}"/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
            </telerik:RadTabItem>
            <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Asset">
                <telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <local:AssetUserCtrl DataContext="{Binding AssetsViewModel}"/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
            </telerik:RadTabItem>
            <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Exchange">
                <telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <local:ExchangeUserCtrl DataContext="{Binding ExchangesViewModel}"/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
            </telerik:RadTabItem>
        </telerik:RadTabControl>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button  Content="Save" Height="20" Width="40"
                    Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel" Height="20" Width="50" Margin="5"
                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="{Binding IsFoundErrorsOnSave, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource AntiStrongestBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding ErrorsOnSaveMessage}" Width="210" ToolTip="{Binding ErrorsOnSaveMessage}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What's the parent element of your `UserControl`?

Comment: The parent control is a Window. <Window  <usercontrol:DefaultsUserCtrl VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Window>

Comment: So you mean that the `UserControl` is the `Content` of the window? Please post your full XAML tree.

Comment: Yes the DefaultsUserCtrl will the context of the window and user control has following XAML <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="{Binding IsFoundErrorsOnSave, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource AntiStrongestBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding ErrorsOnSaveMessage}" Width="210" ToolTip="{Binding ErrorsOnSaveMessage}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

Comment: So are you saying that the text doesn't get trimmed when you decrease the width of the window or what's your issue?

Comment: Yes. The Window will resize based on the data bound to the user controls. The User control has other user controls inside and based on the data bound the content will resize dynamically.  In the end I don't see the trimmed text in the TextBlock unless I hard code the width.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal compilable example of your issue?